# KeyError: '10' when running rosdep install on Linux Mint 10 machine

Tags: ros, rosdep, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I started ROS on Linux Mint in a Virtual Box. Since the virtual Linux was very slow, I installed the full Linux Mint and restarted the Tutorial in the new Linux. Unfortunately when I arrived at the 3rd chapter and tried to install the turtlesim the following error happend:

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_tutorials/turtlesim $ rosdep install turtlesim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rosdep", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(rosdep.main())
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/main.py", line 124, in main
    r = core.Rosdep(verified_packages, robust=options.robust)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 296, in __init__
    self.osi = roslib.os_detect.OSDetect(os_list)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 479, in __init__
    self.detect_os()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 498, in detect_os
    self._os_version = os_class.get_version()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/debian.py", line 124, in get_version
    return self.version_map[self.mint_detector.get_version()]
KeyError: '10'
```

If somebody has an Idea on how to solve it, I would be very happy for any input! I already reinstalled ROS and uninstalled the Virtual box, but it is still not working...

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9606/keyerror:-%2710%27-when-running-rosdep-install-on-linux-mint-10-machine/) by [Toni](https://answers.ros.org/users/366/toni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosdep doesn't support Mint 10 at the moment.  There is a patch to be applied in [ticket 3404](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3404) thanks to flofra.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-13**:
More context here:  http://answers.ros.org/question/1109/compiling-on-linux-mint-11#1847

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like ROS has problems detecting Linux Mint. Maybe [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep/Tutorials/Add%20Support%20for%20an%20OS%20to%20rosdep) will help you as a starting point.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1